# finfo_open - force use of bundled database

Tags: php, file, environment

Looking at [finfo_open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) I don't see a way to *force* use of the bundled magic database..

Namely, if the *MAGIC* environment variable is set, how would you then get PHP to load the bundled database?

```
setenv('MAGIC=');
```

doesn't do the trick, and neither does passing an explicit `null` to `finfo_open` as in

```
finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME, null);
```

The result:

> Warning: finfo_open(): Failed to load magic database at '(null)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unset environment variable `MAGIC` (note the lack of an equals sign):

```
putenv('MAGIC');
```